# Bootstrap 4 navbar collapsing menu with elements on right columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying for a long time to achieve a mobile menu using Bootstrap 4. My main target is to show the 3 Brand Texts and the toggle button in the same row for the mobile menu. But unfortunately when I am clicking the toggle button the 3 brands are going below the collapsed menu. I want 3 brands to stay in the top in one row along with the toggle button even after collapsing the menu. My problem is the collapsing menu is using column width of 100% which is eventually pushing the 3 brands down below the menu. Any help would be appreciating.

**Target Solution**

[image: Target Solution]

**HTML**

```
<body id="page-top">
 <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-primary navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">

    <button class="navbar-toggler hidden-md-up pull-xs-right" data-target="#collapsenav" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">
            ☰
        </button>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
             <div class="navbar-toggleable-sm collapse  text-xs-center" id="collapsenav">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Resume</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home">Brand-1</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home">Brand-2</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home">Brand-3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>   
</body>
```

[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/audhit/pen/rygpbQ)

Comment: It would be better to use the latest alpha 6, instead of alpha 3. Is this possible for you?

Comment: Yes of course I can use alpha 6, but how can it help in order to achieve the solution I am looking for? Any idea @ZimSystem ?

Comment: Also, explain what you expect to see for the non-mobile horizontal version of the menu.. before is collapses into the mobile version.

Comment: Hey the non mobile desktop version will look as it is now looking at my pen..no change required in the desktop version...I am only stuck with mobile version as its pushing down my three brands below the collapsed menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the new Bootstrap 4 alpha 6 flexbox utilities for alignment, and keep the markup simpler:

http://www.codeply.com/go/OFXaPnKx2P

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-inverse bg-primary fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between flex-last">
            <button class="navbar-toggler align-self-end mb-1" data-target="#collapsenav" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">
                ☰
            </button>
            <div class="d-flex w-100 flex-first justify-content-between">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home">Brand-1</a>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home">Brand-2</a>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home">Brand-3</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100" id="collapsenav">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav align-items-center">
                <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Resume</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

[Demo](http://www.codeply.com/go/OFXaPnKx2P)

Currently in alpha 6 [there is a bug](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/21848) that makes a `container` inside the navbar shrink width on small screen. This will be fixed in beta, but until then you just need a little CSS to keep the inner container full width on mobile.

```
@media (max-width:767px) {
    .container {
        width: 100%;
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-right: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, I consider your reply as the final answer as it is very clean and without any repetition of HTML code. It solves the problem I am having nicely.Thanks a lot and cheers! @ZimSystem

Answer (score 1):

Do the 3 brands have to be on the right?

With Bootstrap, you can have the brands on the left easily by just moving the nav-brand  links between the button and the divs for the nav list content. This will make it so your 3 brands stay in place and don't get pushed down.

```
<body id="page-top">
 <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-primary navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
 <button class="navbar-toggler hidden-md-up pull-xs-right" data-target="#collapsenav" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">
            ☰
        </button>
    //move brand items here
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home">Brand-1</a>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home">Brand-2</a>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home">Brand-3</a>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
             <div class="navbar-toggleable-sm collapse  text-xs-center" id="collapsenav">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Resume</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    //delete these out
      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home">Brand-1</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home">Brand-2</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home">Brand-3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>   
</body>
```

If your three brands have to be on the right, then I think you will have to do some bootstrap CSS work to have the brands show on large screens as you have it originally in your code and then hide on smaller screens and show the code as I added above. For example:

```
<body id="page-top">
 <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-primary navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
 <button class="navbar-toggler hidden-md-up pull-xs-right" data-target="#collapsenav" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">
            ☰
        </button>
        //show these here on small screens
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home">Brand-1</a>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home">Brand-2</a>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home">Brand-3</a>
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
             <div class="navbar-toggleable-sm collapse  text-xs-center" id="collapsenav">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Resume</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    //show these below on large screens
      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home">Brand-1</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home">Brand-2</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home">Brand-3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I am still relatively new to coding, so I hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for your tips but cannot consider it as a full-proof solution. But the tweak/workaround by you is also appreciating. Thanks man, cheers!